# select specific para from text file

Tags: python

Sample text:

```
StartString fcchwd
dheoidfjewofd
edeodei
eddeed
dd djded dojef efjefj
fefije efoef;

 StartString wdjkndd
dwojdpjf wodjojd wdjwjdm
wodjow
wdjwdjm ojdowj ww
wdeswjd wdojwod;

#jfejf
/** hfhih **/

dijhfs
wdjw


StartString wkpwkd 
dokowdk djd 
owjidwo;
```

I tried below regex but it is giving only on line after match.

```
r"StartString\s*(.*)\s*"
```

How can i store all sets starting from `StartString` and ending with `;`. Later i want to remove newline from these sets
which can be done with simple `replace` command, but not sure how to figure out this sets. Please suggest.

Comment: Surely you've tried something already. Please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below pattern which is working:

```
import re 

str1 = "StartString fcchwd dheoidfjewofd edeodei eddeed dd djded dojef efjefj fefije efoef;  StartString wdjkndd dwojdpjf wodjojd wdjwjdm wodjow wdjwdjm ojdowj ww wdeswjd wdojwod;  #jfejf  /** hfhih **/ dijhfs wdjw  StartString wkpwkd  dokowdk djd owjidwo;"


regex = re.compile(r'(StartString.+?;)')
l = regex.findall(str1)
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
['StartString fcchwd dheoidfjewofd edeodei eddeed dd djded dojef efjefj fefije efoef;', 'StartString wdjkndd dwojdpjf wodjojd wdjwjdm wodjow wdjwdjm ojdowj ww wdeswjd wdojwod;', 'StartString wkpwkd  dokowdk djd owjidwo;']
```